# Is there any way to use libgpuarray with Intel GPU?

Tags: python, gpu, gpgpu, theano

I'm looking for a way to use Intel GPU as a GPGPU with Theano.
I've already installed Intel OpenCL and libgpuarray, but a test code 'python -c "import pygpu;pygpu.test()"' crashed the process. And I found out `devname` method caused it. It seems there would be a lot more errors.

Is it easy to fixed them to work well? I understand Intel OpenCL project can use GPGPU but it might not be supported by libgpuarray.

**Environment**

- Windows 7 x64
- Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
- Python 2.7 x86 or x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libgpuarray have been made to support OpenCL, but we don't have time to finish it. Many thinks work, but we don't have the time to make sure it work everywhere.

In any cases, you must find an OpenCL version that support that GPU, install it and reinstall libgpuarray to have it use it.

Also, I'm not sure that GPU will give you any speed up. Don't spend too much time on tring to make it work.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is what I was looking for. I'll give it up and try NVIDIA CUDA.